# How do I prevent MS Access VBA from converting objects to strings?

Tags: oop, ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass a collection of Folder objects in a VBA module, but it consistently performs an implicit cast of the objects to String type

```
Function GetFolderFiles(ByRef dir As Object) As Collection
Dim files As Collection
Set files = New Collection
For Each file In dir.files
    Debug.Print TypeName(file)
    files.Add (file)
Next frile
For Each subfolder In dir.SubFolders
    Dim sf As Object
    Set sf = subfolder
    Debug.Print TypeName(sf)
    Dim tmpfiles As Collection
    Set tmpfiles = GetFolderFiles(sf)
    For Each File In tmpfiles
        files.Add (File)
    Next File
Next subfolder
Set GetFolderFiles = files
End Function
```

Here is my test code:

```
Function TestGetFiles()
Dim fso As Object
Dim d As Object
Dim files As Collection

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set d = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\X\Documents\My Web Sites")
Set files = GetFolderFiles(d)
For Each f In files
    Debug.Print TypeName(f)
Next f
End Function
```

As you can see, I'm printing out the TypeName() call's results. When I step through the functions, I get the expected type "File" within GetFolderFiles, but when I iterate over the returned collection, the type of the objects is "String".

1) How do I get a collection of File objects back from my function?

2)More generally, How do I prevent the implicit conversion of Objects to Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between `f` and `(f)`, as illustrated in the code below:

```
Function TestGetFiles()

Dim fso As Object
Dim d As Object, f As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set d = fso.GetFolder("C:\_Stuff\test")

    For Each f In d.files
        Debug.Print TypeName(f), TypeName((f)) '>> File     String
    Next f

End Function
```

`f` is the file itself, but *wrapping `f` in parentheses causes that expression to be evaluated* (resulting in a string: I'm guessing the default property of `File` is its `Name`)
and the result of the evaluation is what gets added to your collection.

Fix: don't use

```
files.Add (File)
```

but

```
files.Add File
```

Hint: any time the VB editor puts a space before your opening `(` means you need to be sure you meant to use those parens. Basically be careful when using parens in a method call unless you're using the `Call` keyword.